# How to enable it, when GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER?

Tags: grub-efi, os-prober

How to activate GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER on Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: You appear to be asking about a change that occurred in grub 2.06 noted here (https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2021-December/041769.html) during the *alpha* stage of Ubuntu 22.04 development. That was noted during QA testing & is reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1955109) but Ubuntu 22.04 LTS had reversed that upstream default prior to *beta* and thus the issue shouldn't exist if you're using an official Ubuntu 22.04 LTS system. Debian & other non-Ubuntu systems have the issue still, so what are you using??  It's just a text file to edit though

Answer (score 1):

The GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER is enabled by default to not search for other bootable partitions.  To disable it so that it detects bootable partitions, modify the `/etc/default/grub` file and add a line that reads:

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
```

Save the file and exit.

Then run `sudo update-grub` and then reboot the system.